# Вывод слова из строки

Tags: c

```
void word_print(char * array,int begin){
    if(begin != 0 || *(array+(begin-1)) != ' '){
        while( *(array+begin)!=' ' && *(array+begin)!='.' && *(array+begin)!=',' && begin != 0){
            begin= begin - 1;
        }
    }
    while( *(array+begin)!=' ' || *(array+begin)!='.' || *(array+begin)!=',' || *(array+begin)!='\0'){
            printf("%c",*(array+begin++));
    }
}
```

На вход функции приходит строка и интовое значение которое указывает на слово которое нужно распечатать.

Проблема в том что второй цикл при вот таких `word_print("1234 56", 7);` аргументах бесконечный, хотя должно сработать условие в `while`

Comment: Вы хотите с конца строки распечатать слово? То есть анализ строки у вас происходит справа налево*

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, нет. мы получаем номер-указатель буквы которая есть в нужном нам слове. Если это не начало строки, и не начало слова, то мы декрементируем номер указатель, пока он не станет на пробел, начало строки или .,

Comment: Ну, если вы уменьшаете позицию, то это и означает, что вы хотите выводить слова с конца предложения, то есть движение идет справа налево. Если печатать с начала строки, то позиция, если она попадает на пробел, должна перемещаться вправо.

Comment: Да, я уже понял, спасибо.

Comment: *"интовое значение которое указывает на слово которое нужно распечатать"* -- интересно, только мне почудилось, что речь о порядковом номере слова в строке?

Comment: нет, т.к. в данном решении задачи работа идет именно со символами, а уже основываясь на наличие определенных символов в слове возвращает значение.

Comment: Что "нет" - не мне одному показалось, что формулировка задачи и код  не соответвуют друг другу?

Comment: мы не получаем номер слова в строке, а номер символа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запишите правильно условие цикла

```
while( *(array+begin)!=' ' && *(array+begin)!='.' && *(array+begin)!=',' && *(array+begin)!='\0'){
        printf("%c",*(array+begin++));
```

Правда перед этим циклом в конце `if` предложения добавьте

```
++begin;
```